# Multiplication property for symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $M$,  $D\times D$ is a symmetric matrix and $a$ and $b$ are vectors of dimension $D\times 1$. Can we assume that

$a^{T}Mb=(b^{T}M^{T}a)^{T}=b^{T}Ma$ ??

Because $a^{T}Mb$ is a scalar thus we can take it's transpose ??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course since it's a scalar we can transpose it, there is a little typo in the second term

$$a^{T}Mb=(b^{T}M^{T}a)^T=b^{T}M^Ta=b^{T}Ma$$